# model.eval for class with field of network - pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have a class model with field of pre-trained resnet
something like:

```
class A(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.resnet = get_resnet()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.resnet(x)

...
```

now Im doing

```
model = A()
...
model.eval()
```

Is it ok or shuld I overwrite the `eval`, `train` functions?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

It's OK.

## Long answer

As the [`nn.Module.train()`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1579) runs recursively like this.

```
self.training = mode
for module in self.children():
    module.train(mode)
return self
```

And the `nn.Module.eval()` is just calling `self.train(False)`

So as long as `self.resnet` is an `nn.Module` subclass. You don't need to bother about it and practically every method in `nn.Module` except `forward` will affect all the sub modules.

You can test this by

```
model = A()
...
model.eval()
print(model.resnet.training)  # should be False
```

If you get `False` then everything is fine. If you get something else then there's something wrong with the `get_resnet()`.